# Our application is removed by Facebook

Tags: facebook, administration

Our application Marketland (appid: 186712578038225) is removed without a reason. Application link http://apps.facebook.com/marketland shows "The page you requested was not found" error.

In addition, all the admin accounts are locked. Some got back the accounts but most of us including me still can not access our Facebook account because of the sms confirmation messages which never come.

We've received these emails from facebook. It seems like "Cullen Walsh" has changed canvas_url. His facebook account says he is a Facebook employee.

#### 1.

App settings for Marketland (app id = 186712578038225) changed by API from 10.66.138.54 on Mon, 10 Dec 2012 14:48:12 -0800
Changed settings:
Old Value   New Value
Object Type display:
is_in_trashcan  1
Object Type Display:
type    907
oid 453308094712004
name    _Single Unit Config
singular    quest
plural  quests
article a
property_config {"quest":{"type":"reference","display_name":"Quest","formal_name":"quest","reference_object_type":453307848045362,"required_group":"primary_objects","reference_assoc_type":185342298257295}}
formal_name quest
app_id  186712578038225
Object Type quest:
Object Type Quest:
Action Type Unlock:
assoc_id    505438416134191
singular_present    completes
plural_present  complete
singular_past   completed
plural_past completed
button_text Complete
app_preposition on
graph_api_name  complete
imperative  complete
tenses_disabled 2
Action Type unlock:
Aggregation _Single Unit Config:
sort_by {"direction":"DESC","expression":"timestamp"}
ui_template_type    poster
ui_template_data    {"poster":{"caption":"","caption1":"","caption2":"","caption3":""},"number":{"number":"{}","units":""},"map":{"header_0":"","number_0":"","units_0":"","header_1":"","number_1":"","units_1":"","header_2":"","number_2":"","units_2":"","route":"","highlighted_points_count":"0"}}
created_time    1349870338
single_unit 1
Action Type Complete:
Action Type complete:

#### 2.

App settings for Marketland (app id = 186712578038225) changed by Cullen Walsh from 10.171.31.43 on Mon, 10 Dec 2012 15:07:01 -0800
Changed settings:
Old Value   New Value
canvas_page_url marketland

#### 3

App settings for Marketland (app id = 186712578038225) changed by API from 10.171.90.23 on Mon, 10 Dec 2012 15:08:53 -0800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can appeal apps that have been disabled here:

https://developers.facebook.com/appeal

There is more information available at:

https://www.facebook.com/help/155308851202619/

Comment: We appealed. In an hour they enabled the application. Thanks for the help.